# starting circshift based on index of a number using find in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, octave, bit-shift

I'm trying to start the circshift at the specific index of a number using the find command  how can I do this?  See example code below

```
%test find and circshift
a=[3:2:11]

%find index of number and start there
a_ind=find(a==9)
b=circshift(a,[0 a_ind])
```

I get a =[3 5 7 9 11]

a_ind = 4

b = [ 5 7 9 11 3]

**I'm trying to get the circshift (b) to start at 9 and have 
b = [9 11 3 5 7]**

**Please note a_ind will vary so I just can't have circshift starting at 2 each time**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
>> circshift(a,[0 (length(a)-a_ind+1)])
ans =

    9   11    3    5    7
```

If I try with a different vector `a`:

```
>> a=[3:1:11]
a =

    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11

>> a_ind=find(a==9)
a_ind =  7
>> circshift(a,[0 (length(a)-a_ind+1)])
ans =

    9   10   11    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option that's good for vectors:

```
a=[3:2:11];
shift = find(a==9);

circshift(a(:), -shift + 1)'
```

`a(:)` guarantees you a column vector and `circshift` shifts on the row dimension i.e. it needs a column vector. Then just transpose again at the end to recover your row vector. You want to shift left so you must specify a negative shift.